# Two Subnet Routing

Tags: routing, windows-server-2019

Consider the following scenario

Network 1
Switch (Call it Switch1) with the following connected appliances
Old Windows 2008 Server (Old Domain Controller) with interface IP 192.168.2.113 255.255.255.0 (No Gateway)
ISP Router for Internet service with Ip Address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

Network 2
Switch 48 port (call it Switch2) with the following connected appliances
Windows Server 2019 (New Domain Controller with new Name and DNS/DHCP Service enabled) and
Interface with static IP 10.3.15.5 255.255.255.0 Gateway 10.3.15.1

Windows Server 2019 with Remote and Routing services and two Interface: One 10.3.15.1 255.255.255.0 no gateway and connect to Switch2

other with 192.168.2.50 255.255.255.0 with No Gateway, and this interface is connected to
the Switch1
Now I enable routing with the routing service in this server
when I ping 192.168.2.113 from this server I got a reply with no issue

when I ping 192.168.2.113 from the first server 10.3.15.5 I got NO Reply
I do not know what is the issue please help!

[first general tab of routing service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcE3h.jpg)
[second is the routing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiLCf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagrams help a lot when asking questions like these.

If I understand correctly, based on the information you've provided, your Windows Server 2019 machine (10.3.15.1/192.168.2.50) is supposed to be routing between the 2 networks/switches,  a ping from 10.3.15.5 to 192.168.2.113 is *supposed to* look like this:

```
10.3.15.5 --> 10.3.15.1 --> 192.168.2.113           #Request
192.168.2.113 --> 192.168.2.50 --> 10.3.15.5        #Reply
```

The 10.3.15.5 machine looks fine, but you've said the 192.168.2.113 machine has no gateway set, so it's likely that what is actually happening is this:

```
10.3.15.5 --> 10.3.15.1 --> 192.168.2.113           #Request
192.168.2.113 --X--                                 #Reply
```

Since 192.168.2.113 has no gateway, it doesn't know where to send the reply.

Set the gateway to 192.168.2.50, or alternatively add a static route for 10.3.15.0/24 via 192.168.2.50

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that your missing a static route 10.3.15.5 doesnt seem to know how to get to 192.168.2.113.  Please provide the routing table for the 10.3.15.5 host.

Comment: Okay, I will provide it later. However, I did routing in the default configuration,( Next Next). I added another device to switch one with Ip 192.168.2.114 but the same issue no reply!. From what I remember there is no static route in the static route part of the routing service, meanwhile In (General Part) I can see both interfaces.

Comment: I modify the post with two screenshots for general tab and routing table